# Basic question about modules functions and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following two code samples do the same thing. Am I interpreting how they work correctly?

How could I directly check if my interpretation is correct using python?

In code sample A the `timeit` module is imported and then the `timeit` function is used from the `timeit` module (`timeit.timeit`) - is this correct?

In code sample B `t` is an instance of the `timer` class, and the `timer` class is in the `tiemit` module. In code sample B, `t.timeit()` is using a `timeit()` method that's part of the timer class. The `timeit()` method used by `t.timeit()` is not the `timeit` function in code sample A (`timeit.timeit`), as the `timeit` method in code sample B is in the `timer` class, while in code sample A the `timeit` method is a function in the `timeit` module, and is not part of a class. Is this correct?

Code sample A:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"')
```

Code sample B:

```
import timeit
t = timeit.Timer('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"')
t.timeit()
```

Comment: It is pretty much [spelled out in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) that it is the same thing.

Comment: You can also see it [from the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/timeit.py#L210).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/timeit.py#L229

Module level `timeit` is just a convenience wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Both of your codes will have the same effect, you can see this by running them, however the one you choose to execute will depend on your intention.

You can read more about this here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-method-function-python/

This is also an excellent website for self taught programming and beginners.